# Uploading Images to LaTex Overleaf

Tags: image, latex

I am creating figures with python that are saved in the local directory with commands in PNG format:

```
plt.savefig('')
dfi.export(df, '')
```

I am using Overleaf. How can I upload my images so that they are updated every time that I run my Python File and the PNGs are different?

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support here. I unfortunately can't really answer your question positively, so I'll just comment: We don't have an API to update a file in a project if the file lives in your computer. For files fetched via a URL, this is possible though -- there's a button to refresh the file.

Comment: @TomGiavas In case you have a paid overleaf account, maybe https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization or https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub could help?